# How do I access a many-to-many table in jpa?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

This is the user class with a @manytomany mapping, I want it to be unidirectional.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="user_drivers", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="driver_id"))
    private Set<Driver> driverSet;

    public User() {
    }
}
```

A table is created with both keys from user and driver, but I don't know how to access it within my repository.

```
@Query(value="select u.user_id from user_drivers")
    List<?> findAllByIdAndDriver(Long id);
```

This gives an error: Can't resolve symbol 'user_drivers'

```
@Query(value="select id,driverSet from User ")
    List<?> findAllByIdAndDriver(Long id);
```

And this results in a nester query exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method naming is confusing. When you say something like `findByIdAndSomethingElse` you're implying that you're doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = ? AND SOMETHING_ELSE = ?;
```

There's missing information here, since you don't share your complete repository or `Driver` implementations, but assuming you want all user IDs from a `Driver` with a specific ID, you can simply do this:

```
@Query("select driver.userId from Driver driver where driver.id = ?1")
public List<Long> findUserIdsByDriverId(long id);
```

The `?1` is the first argument. You can refer to subsequent arguments with `?2, ?3, ... , ?n`

Comment: I am trying to get all driver ids based on a single user id. The problem I have is that I don't know how to correctly set the mapping/ access the joint table.

Comment: I have 2 classes User and Driver which I am persisting, however I wanted it to be unidirectional on the user side.https://prnt.sc/rd2v1x

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct queries should be like:

```
@Query(value="select u.userId from UserDrivers u")
```

and

```
@Query(value="select u.id, u.driverSet from User u")
```

For the 1st query, I'm assuming that entity for the other table is called `UserDrivers` and its column - `userId` (according to Java naming conventions).

Comment: I have 2 tables, users and driver, and I want to store a user id with multiple driver ids in the manytomany table but I can't seem to figure out how to access the joint table. The table that you have suggested doesn't appear when i type the name in the query, only users/driver tables are suggested. https://prnt.sc/rd2sy2

Comment: Yes, I indicated in my answer that the question doesn't have information about the correct name of the entity for the table with drivers. So I assumed that it's called `UserDrivers`.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question, I will try to be more concise in the future. Thanks anyway for trying to help me.

Comment: Sure, glad you eventually found the way to solve your problem)

Answer (score 1):

Found what I needed thanks to the answers pointing me in the right direction.

```
@Query(value="select u.driverSet from User u where u.id=?1")
    List<?> getDriverSet(Long id);
```